# Why is this function not injective?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm working through some of Do Carmo's Differential Geometry excercises. In one of those excercises he asks if the map $f(u,v)= (u+v,u+v,uv)$ with $u>v$ is a parametrization for the plane. In the solution he says it isn't because it is not injective but I can't find a way to prove it. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that this mapping isn't onto (surjective).  This appears to be the plane $x = y$ however, you cannot get the point $(0, 0, 0)$ from this plane because this would require $u = v = 0$ and that would not satisfy the constraint $u > v$ (note that you _can_ get $x = y = 0$ by choosing $v = -u, u > 0$, but then you just end up with $x = y = 0, z = -u^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in fact injective. Let $a = u + v$ and $b = u v$. Then $x^2 - a x + b = (x - u) (x - v)$; and $u > v$, so we deduce:
\begin{align}
u & = \frac{a + \sqrt{a^2 - 4 b}}{2} \\
v & = \frac{a - \sqrt{a^2 - 4 b}}{2}
\end{align}
(Note that $a^2 - 4b = (u - v)^2 > 0$, so these formulae make sense.)